# How to set up a title at the top of a ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

In my app I have a tabBarViewController, and this is the first bar:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationItem.title = "RECENTS"
  }

}
```

this is the custom class:

```
class CustomTabBar: UITabBarController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let firstVC = FirstViewController()
    let secondVC = SecondViewController()
    let thirdVC = ThirdViewController()

    firstVC.tabBarItem.title = "RECENT"
    secondVC.tabBarItem.title = "MAP"
    thirdVC.tabBarItem.title = "SETTINGS"

    firstVC.title = "RECENT"
    secondVC.title = "MAP"
    thirdVC.title = "SETTINGS"

    viewControllers = [firstVC,secondVC,thirdVC]
  }

}
```

So my question is: How can I put a title at the top of the view controller?
In the previous code I tried, but it's not working!

Something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `title` property is shown when a view controller is wrapped in a `UINavigationController`. Here's some code replacing the last line (i.e. the `viewControllers` assignment) in  of your example that should do the trick:

```
let firstNC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstVC)
let secondNC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondVC)
let thirdNC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: thirdVC)
viewControllers = [firstNC,secondNC,thirdNC]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I've just found a solution on: https://swiftludus.org/how-to-navigate-between-view-controllers-in-ios/.

Comment: For your understanding, the "Embed In" menu item in Interface Builder described in that tutorial does exactly the same as my code example: it takes an existing `UIViewController` and wraps it inside a `UINavigationController`. Then you display that "wrapping" navigation controller (in the example, the navigation controller and not the view controller is added to the tab bar controller), which in turn handles display of its "wrapped" view controller (including the `title`). Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)
   self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "My Title"
}
```

This should work. I hope it helps you.

Or if you can try this.

```
let vc3 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: SearchVC())
vc3.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "vyhledavani")
vc3.title = "Vyhledat"
vc3.tabBarItem.tag = 2
viewControllers = [vc3, ...]
```

Comment: Thank you very much but it's not work, probably I put it in a wrong place.